# positioning axis label relative to tick labels

Tags: pgfplots

Does anyone know how to position an axis label relative to the tick labels  using axis coordinates or cm rather than `anchor=near ticklabel` command in, for instance, `y label style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel}`?

Comment: This `\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={10pt}}` does the job perfectly for the entire document. I only want to change the label position for one graph.

Comment: ... then pass this option to the respective axis ?

Comment: Please, do elaborate

Comment: What I mean is say `\begin{axis}[/pgfplots/label shift={10pt},...` to localize the effect to an axis or `\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/label shift={10pt},...` to localize it to a group of axis environments within a `tikzpicture`. The problem is that there is no MWE, so really no one is benefitting from our conversation. If you post an MWE (minimal working document) like in your previous question, I can almost guarantee you that you will immediately get a useful answer (and reputation points ... ).